# How can I display @total in view display rest export in json format?

Tags: views

In a block or page display view i can put Result Summary @total in header. But in rest export display view does not use header plugins.

How can i get @total in rest export json format?

I have search in drupal.org and StackExchange, but no luck.

Is there a way to get @total Drupal 9?

Comment: I recently released a module to do this: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rest_serializer_extra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a custom serializer in a custom module as shown in https://gist.github.com/svetlio/79f3c32667b21d89ed03cdb660308668 and select the "Custom Serializer"(custom name you give for serializer) in the Views Display as shown in the figure below

[image]

As @kevin suggested there is a module for this now - https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rest_serializer_extra

Comment: This has more features. https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rest_serializer_extra

Comment: Thank you, ill look at your module